# Change Default Uploading for Digital Ocean Space to Public for files from Filezilla pro

Tags: digital-ocean, spaces, filezilla, droplet

I have millions of small images about 1KB-5KB, which I need to upload them to the Digital Ocean Space. 
I have Filezilla Pro , and  I can successfully upload the files to the Digital Ocean Space using the Filezilla Pro , but when I upload those files to the Digital Ocean Space using the Filezilla Pro , their default statuses are `Private`.

As a result accessing those files through a URL is not possible as I get an

> Access Denied Error.

Another way is using the Rclone but for that I need to upload those files to the Digital Ocean's Droplet by zipping them and then using the Rclone to upload them to Digital Ocean space. 
But it's very long process because I have to do the zipping process from Windows and then transfer the files to the droplet in order to unzip them and upload them to the Digital Ocean's Droplet using Rclone.

How could I upload all of my files , directly  , with a public status from Windows using the FileZilla Pro or any other client similar to it?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How it's an off-topic ?

Comment: My comment includes a link that details what questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow.